# Trying to populate a ComboBox in Access ContinuousForm (different recordset for each row) by calling a function from the ControlSource in the designer

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2010, adodb

I am trying to populate a Combo Box on a continuous form by calling a function in the Control Source field of the data tab in the Combo Cox designer. Each Combo Box on each row will have a different recordset based upon the different parameters that are passed into each function call.

The problem is it is not populating the Combo Boxes.

In the designer:

`=LaterRevisions([DocumentCode],[LadRevision],[LadId])`

[image: The Property Sheet, Data tab]

The function:

(Note I have commented out the return type in the function definition since with this it doesn't even appear to execute the function!? (doesn't trip a breakpoint in the body of the function))

```
Public Function LaterRevisions (DocumentCode As String, LadRevision As String, LadId As Integer) 'As ADODB.Recordset
On Error GoTo ErrHandler

Dim Record As Variant
Dim dbs As Object
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim qdf As QueryDef
Dim sql As String

Set dbs = CurrentDb()

Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("qryLaterRevisionsByRow")
sql = qdf.sql
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

  With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
    .CommandText = sql

    With .Parameters("DocumentCode")
      .Type = adVarChar
      .Value = DocumentCode
    End With

    With .Parameters("LadRevision")
      .Type = adVarChar
      .Value = LadRevision
    End With

    With .Parameters("LadId")
      .Type = adInteger
      .Value = LadId
    End With

  End With

  cmd.Execute

  Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
  With rs
    .CursorLocation = adUseServer
    .Open cmd, , adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
  End With

  If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
    Debug.Print rs.RecordCount ' does get records
    'Set Me.[cboLatestrevision].Recordset = rs ' will set this recordset (but sets all rows to the same in continuous form)
    Set LaterRevisions = rs ' function returns individual recordset for each row, but doesn't populate the combo
  End If

ExitHandler:
    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    ' handle error
    Resume ExitHandler
End Function
```

Despite when stepping through the code it clearly shows the recordset being populated, and when calling the function from the Form_Load event, it populates a recordset (hence the function is returning one) (see test code below), it doesn't populate the Combo Box.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim myVar As ADODB.Recordset
Set myVar = LaterRevisions("XXX", "YYY", 999)

For myI = 1 To myVar.RecordCount
  Debug.Print myVar.Fields("LatestRevision") ' prints correct values
  myVar.MoveNext
Next myI
End Sub
```

The saved query (qryLaterRevisionsByRow):

```
PARAMETERS DocumentCode Text ( 255 ), LadRevision Text ( 255 ), LadId Long;
SELECT tblLaterRevisions.LatestRevision
FROM tblLaterRevisions
WHERE (((tblLaterRevisions.LatestRevision)>[LadRevision]) AND ((tblLaterRevisions.DocumentCode)=[DocumentCode]) AND ((tblLaterRevisions.LadId)=[LadId]));
```

I have these references:

[image: VBA References]

I'm using Windows 7 Enterprise, MS Access 2010

Comment: Makes no sense to call function from ControlSource property if you want to change a combobox RowSource list. Call procedure (a Sub is probably more appropriate than a Function) in form CurrentEvent and/or another control AfterUpdate event whose value dictates the list and set RowSource property. This is akin to a cascading (dependent) combobox - RowSource list is conditional on some other value in record.

Comment: Hello June7. Your reply is not clear to me. I know I can use a sub to set the control's recordset but this will set the same recordset for each continuous form row. I need a different recordset for each row.

Comment: RowSource will be changed for combobox when record gets focus. It is not possible for combobox to have different RowSource in each record at same time. There is only one combobox and setting its properties affects ALL instances of combobox.